# How to set custom image name in docker compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up -d` the image is pulled and named as `ghcr.io/username/myimage`. I want it to be named just `myimage`. For this I have to manually run the commands below. Is there a way to specify the custom image name directly in docker compose file?

```
docker pull ghcr.io/username/myimage:latest
docker tag ghcr.io/username/myimage:latest myimage:latest
docker rmi -f ghcr.io/username/myimage:latest
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  devcontainer:
    image: ghcr.io/username/myimage:latest
    command: sleep infinity
    container_name: myimage
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to specify the custom image name directly in docker compose file?

There is not; the `image` directive is all about telling Docker what image to use; it's not meant to be a general purpose tool for retagging images.

However! You can use a simple workaround to do what you want. Create a dummy Dockerfile, like this:

```
FROM ghcr.io/username/myimage:latest
```

And then structure your compose file like this:

```
services:
  devcontainer:
    image: myimage
    build:
      context: .
    command: sleep infinity
    container_name: myimage
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Now when you run `docker compose build`, it will build image `myimage`.

Comment: This workaround worked! When I do `docker-compose build` it indeed creates just `myimage` image. However, I actually use `devcontainer.json` and when I select *Reopen in Container* in VS Code it creates both `ghcr.io/username/myimage` and anouther one `myimage`. I'm not sure should I ask this in a separate post?

Comment: It creates both tags because you are still pulling the original image.

Comment: But, if I delete the image and do just `docker-compose build` I end up with only `myimage` image. But, if I use `devcontainer.json` I end up with both `ghcr.io/username/myimage` and `myimage` images.